# Rails app - Canvas Theme JS not loading as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with my Rails app and the JS from the Canvas theme from Themeforest, which is not loading as it should.

On the home page all is running fine (logo is changing size when scrolling, counter in the footer working and the scrollbar in the end of the page to go to top is visible).

Even though the JS is loaded via application.js for all sites (in application.hmtl.erb) - on the category pages (e.g. /categories/1), the logo is not changing in size, the jquery to adjust the position of the products is not working but the counter in the footer is.

My application.js is loading in the following order:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require plugins
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require functions
//= require turbolinks
//= require_self
```

Can someone help me how to settle these issues? You can find the website deployed here: [trendio100.herokuapp.com](http://trendio100.herokuapp.com)